# how can convert var to List c#

Tags: c#, list, var

I would like to convert var to list value . I am getting 'myobj' var value. Now how can i convert to CandidateResume list ?.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090 };
 var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);
```

My CandidateResume class like this

```
public class CandidateResume
        {

            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string summary { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public string compensation { get; set; }
            public string education { get; set; }
            public string expertise { get; set; }
            public string years { get; set; }
            public string relocation { get; set; }
            public string resume { get; set; }
            public string resumeExtension { get; set; }
            public string resumeMimeType { get; set; }

        }
```

Please see this current item value in screenshot [image]

How can i catch item value ?

```
     foreach (var item in myobj)
                    {
 WebScrappingCandidate webScrappingCandidate = new WebScrappingCandidate();

}
```

Comment: There is no `var` *type*, instead your `myobj` is *a specific type* that the compiler inferred from the right side of the `=`. In this case, it would be a `List<List<CandidateResume>>`.

Comment: I am getting this way 'var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);'

Comment: `myobj` is already `List<List<CandidateResume>>`, you can use this type instead of `var`

Comment: Now i need the value to save this object 
WebScrappingCandidate webScrappingCandidate = new WebScrappingCandidate(); How can i will get CandidateResume class object value ?

Comment: @Liton Given that we don't know the relationship between "WebScrappingCandidate" and "CandidateResume" we can't help with that part.

Comment: WebScrappingCandidate & CandidateResume like same class .

Comment: I want like this item value 
`List<List<CandidateResume>> myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);                
                
foreach (var item in myobj)
                {

                    WebScrappingCandidate webScrappingCandidate = new WebScrappingCandidate();
                    webScrappingCandidate.FullName=item.
                   
                }`

Comment: Thanks i got it 
`foreach (var item in myobj)
                {
                    foreach(var r in item)
                    {
                        WebScrappingCandidate webScrappingCandidate = new WebScrappingCandidate();
                        webScrappingCandidate.FullName = r.name;                    
                    }                                       
                }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list, the `Deserialize` method returns a typed result:

```
List<List<CandidateResume>> myobj =
  jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);
```

When you loop through that, each item is a list:

```
foreach (List<CandidateResume> item in myobj) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Deserialize<T>` returns a `T` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx)), which means `myObj` is already of type: `List<List<CandidateResume>>`.

Remember, `var` is *not* a type, it just uses type inference to be shorthand for: "Be whatever type I'm being assigned to".

To "flatten" this list, you could just use `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (CandidateResume resume in myObj.SelectMany(i => i))
{

}
```

Of course, there are other methods as well, but the crux of the answer is that you *already have* a list of candidate resumes. No conversion required.